# Turning a UITableView into an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimage

I have got a `UITableView`, and I want to capture the visible portion of it, and put it into a `UIImage`. Any way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Self-answered below

Comment: a uitableview is a uiscrollview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709429/saving-uiscrollview-to-uiimage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. All of the answers would work with a UIView, but not with a UITableView - at least not when the table has scrolled. When scrolled, the captured image would appear black or transparent. I had tried similar solutions as the ones below before. I guess people assumed the answer was obvious, and that's why I was down-voted - for being naughty enough to ask such an obvious question.

Anyway, the real solution is that you have to use the table's contentOffset:

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    UIView *renderedView = tableView;
    CGPoint tableContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(renderedView.bounds.size, renderedView.opaque, 0.0);
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(contextRef, 0, -tableContentOffset.y);
    [tableView.layer renderInContext:contextRef];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(someView.bounds.size);
[someView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051630/save-uiviews-representation-to-file).

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIImage *)captureView {

//hide controls if needed
CGRect rect = [yourTableView bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [yourTableview.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tableView.bounds.size);
[tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Maybe those posts will be helpful
[Rendering UIView with its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788662/rendering-uiview-with-its-children)

[Saving UIView contents in iOS 4 with real size of the images inside (i.e. scale contentes up for save)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213529/saving-uiview-contents-in-ios-4-with-real-size-of-the-images-inside-i-e-scale)

[Safe way to render UIVIew to an image on background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348962/safe-way-to-render-uiview-to-an-image-on-background-thread)